# Eee PC - Create USB Recovery Drive w/ Files Copied From Recovery Partition

Tags: ghost

I have an Eee PC 1005HAB whose hard disk has failed.  I have no recovery CD/DVD, but I did previously back up the contents of the recovery partition, and would like to use them to create a bootable USB to reinstall the factory settings on the new hard drive.

Since I simply copied all the files in the recovery partition, rather than hitting F9 during boot and running through the process to create a recovery disk or drive, how do I now use the files to create a bootable USB drive that will do the recovery?

In the BIOS I have disabled boot booster and set external drives to the top of the boot priority, but simply copying all the recovery partion files to a usb doesn't allow it to be booted from.  I've downloaded the HP utility for creating bootable USB drives and have tried using it to make the USB drive bootable, but I'm not sure what to do with the ghost image and utilities from the recovery partition to get the process to start properly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured this out after a lot of frustration.  The recovery partition basically includes the files for a WinPE bootdisk, the executable file for Norton Ghost 11, and the Ghost disk images themselves.

With this in mind, I tried to run the Ghost32.exe file on another Windows XP computer, thinking I could restore the image to the new netbook drive plugged in externally to a SATA-to-USB converter, but Ghost wouldn't open due to a conflict with the version of advapi.dll in XP SP3.  Unfortunately, I didn't have any Pre-SP3 computers around and didn't care to downgrade any.

I also couldn't turn the WinPE files from the recovery partition into a bootable environment on a USB or CD/DVD for the life of me, but I was able to download [Bart's PE Builder](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) to make a bootable environment from a Windows 2003 install disk -- all of our XP computers are OEM, which doesn't seem to work with Bart's.  The first PE disk I made with Bart's would boot OK from a USB CD-ROM drive plugged into the Eee-PC, but couldn't find the new hard drive.  Neither diskpart nor dskchk from the Bart's menu would locate the new drive.

To fix this, I downloaded the SATA Drivers for the Eee-PC 1005HAB [from here](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?modelname=Eee%20PC%201005HAB&SLanguage=en-us), and unzipped and placed the entire folder (called 'AHCI') in the pebuilder disk drivers directory (c:\pebuilder3110a\drivers\SCSIAdapter), where it was automatically included in the next build.  I also placed the ghost.exe in its own folder whose path I entered in the 'Custom' area of the pebuilder GUI, so I could include the ghost program on the disk.  I built the ISO and burned it to a CD, booted the Eee-PC from the external USB CD drive, and the BartPE environment now found the disk and let me create a primary partition on it with diskpart.

Next, I opened the A43 file explorer from the Bart's menu and located the ghost32.exe file on the CD and ran it.  Ghost opened fine, and I chose to restore 'Disk' > 'From Image', and browsed to a USB thumbdrive to which I had previously copied the Ghost images form the recovery partition ('1005HA_ENG_WinXP_02.06.08_2010.01.06.GHO' and '1005HA_ENG_WinXP_02.06.08_2010.01.06.001').  I selected the .GHO file, accepted the partitions and sizes Ghost said it would create on the drive and started the recovery.  After about 10-15 minutes, it completed, I rebooted the netbook and unplugged the external drives, and it booted into a new XP installation.  Since I replaced the failed drive with a larger one, I merged the space left over with the 'D' drive.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

My sister's eee pc 1001px hard drive became corrupted and would no longer boot.  Her options were to lose all of her files, send it away to asus for a HD replacement which could take some time.  I took the HD out, used GetDataBack for NTFS and was able to recover her files and the factory recovery image.  Then I was left with the same issue you were confronted with: How to get the recovery image on to the new HD.  Your instructions were my savior however I dont own a USB cd-rom drive so I had to figure out how to boot from USB.  Found great instructions here [Pe Builder USB](http://users.telenet.be/Robvdb/BootPEUSB_UK.htm)

and was able to boot from the usb drive with the image files in a separate folder.  I then ran the ghost32.exe and was able to boot into xp.